# How can I use two select elements (one being a cloned element of the other) and have seperate values for each?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some code which adds a cloned div of the child element and increments its id by 1 for every cloned element.

```
var c = $(".child:last").attr("id").replace('child', '');
var cloned;
$("#addMore").on('click', function() {
    cloned = $('#child' + c);

    $("#child" + c).clone(true).attr('id', 'child' + (++c)).insertAfter(cloned);
   
});
```

In this child element a select input is contained, which when a specific option is selected, appends some other div elements below it.

```
var div = $('<div class="row" id="price_div_standard"></div>');
$('#second' + c).append(div);
var div1 = $('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>');
div.append(div1);
var div2 = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
div1.append(div2);
var label = $('<label class="form-label">Τιμή</label>');
div2.append(label);
var input = $('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_price[]" id="price" placeholder="Τιμή" readonly>');
div2.append(input);
input.val(<?php echo $taskj['task_price_standard']; ?>);
```

This is the code I've tried but the appended div won't attach itself to each select element I change, only to the latter.
Any help as to how I can approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would recommend reading [mcve] as it looks like there is missing code from your question.

Comment: From the little code you've provided, without context, this line `$('#second' + c).append(div);` will always append to your last element.  Because `c` is globally changed.   I would expect a `this` in there somewhere at the minimum, but without knowing how/when/where your append code is called, can't help further.

Comment: I suggest you *remove* the auto-incrementing ID (remove the `second+n` ID from all elements, including the source) - it's not helping you and there are better ways to achieve whatever the auto-incrementing ID is trying to do.   Normally, relative DOM navigation.